# How search in a list of coordinate in efficient way

Tags: java, arrays, performance, coordinates

I'm tring to use a efficient way to search if one Coordinate (that is not in arrys) is in arrays of coordinates. I wouldn't read the entire arrays I would a better solution. Anyone can help me?

Comment: If they are in some sort of logical order you can divide and conquer.

Comment: If these are 2 dimensional coordinates (like GPS) an quadtree might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As Chief Two Pencils commented, this only works if you have some kind of ordering principle on your array. There are lots of good data types you could use to help you with this: [Range trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_tree), and [k-d Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) are a few that spring to mind.

If you can't change the structure of your data, you still have options. I can imagine an algorithm where you filter by x-coordinate, and then filter those by y-coordinate, and the performance wouldn't even be terrible.

Comment: #Jason Mmmm I explain you. I have two Point and I must search the car path between two points, but I can selection another point in the map and I must verify that Point is or not in the car path previusly selected. I don't think there is  a kind of order in a car path or I wrong?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on how the list of points was constructed. A Point is just a pair of integers, and obviously integers can be ordered. With some work, you can order Points as well; the Wikipedia articles I linked to show you some possibilities

Comment: Thanks Jason for your advice!!

Comment: @user3806720 we thank people by either voting up or accepting their answers